# Extracting key from the nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following dataset in python which has dictionary data type

```
D={'name1':{'college':'EST','height':44,'weight':90},
   'name2':{'college':'WST','height':34,'weight':55},
   'name3':{'college':'ZST','height':76,'weight':44}}

 so on
```

I want to extract name the name of the person with maximumn height.

How this can be done in python?
so far I am not able to do following but only I got max height value.Now how to get the key like was it name1 or name2 or name3?

```
max([k['height'] for k in D.values()])
```

Comment: To translate that to your dataset: `max(D, key=lambda k: D[k].get('height', float('-inf')))` if the `height` key might be missing, otherwise `max(D, key=lambda k: D[k]['height'])` will do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't get how your lambda function is behaving like a `for` loop. and how does it know to return the 'key` and not the value of height?

Comment: @MartijnPieters can the same functionality that you used return max height too?

Comment: @khan: You need to pass a sequence of whatever you want returned to `max()`, and the `key` function is used by the function to determine which one of those values to select as the maximum. `max(d['height'] for d in D.values())` gives you *just* the maximum height value; no key is required as your height values are already the kind of value you wanted to return and can be compared directly.